# Is there a way to offset the default grid?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I would like to offset the way the default grid is displayed.

Currently the thicker grid lines start at 0,0,0 and are spaced 1 blender unit apart.

I am not looking to alter the spacing, I would just like to know if I can change the thicker lines to start at .5 blender units away, either on all axis or just specific ones, say just x & y.

The effect of this assuming the offset is applied to all axis, should be a 1x1x1 thicker grid line cube with 0,0,0 at the center.

Comment: Blender's grid is not very configurable, I don't think that is possible as far as I know. Maybe use a subdivided mesh object instead, and disable the grid?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I'll give it go. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to change the size as Patdog stated but as far as I'm aware the only way to offset/ move the grid is using Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>N</kbd> key to open the Properties Display. Change scale to half Blender units. If you want add sub-division of 10 for example for the sub-units. Subdivisions are visible in orthographic mode.

[image]

Comment: This works for what I was trying to accomplish, thanks.